# CGContextStrokeRect is drawing only a side of rect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sdk, core-graphics

I need to draw a rect filled with color and its border...
the rect is filled with color properly but the outside border is partially drawn, just the right side of the rect is drawn!

The generated UIImage is going to be used in a UITableViewCell's imageView.

```
- (UIImage *)legendItemWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect outside = CGRectMake(128, 128, 128, 128);
    CGRect legend = CGRectInset(outside, 1, 1);

    NSLog(@"Outside: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(outside));
    NSLog(@"Legend: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(legend));

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, legend);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, outside);

    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: i checked your code on simulator and it's fine. That said I think the issue might be related with the Context bounds which is`self.view.frame.size`

Comment: can you try to use it in a tableview with cell.imageView.image = [self legendItemWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

Comment: it's not fine then. However to fix it you have to pass proper CGSize to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() not the self.view.frame.size. I'd suggest to pass only the size you need so, i.e. CGSizeMake(128+128+2,128+128+2). Then it displays ok

Comment: @Michal Zygar - looks like you solved it.  Recommend posting as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you pass self.view.frame.size to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() and then use drawn rectangle in array, it is downscaled and the border is obfuscated. Try to pass only the size you need so, i.e. CGSizeMake(2*128+128+2,2*128+128+2). Then it displays ok