# CGContextStrokeRect not appearing in view

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to draw a colored rectangle that has a border if it is selected, but I can't seem to get the boarder to draw. The colored rectangle appears in the correct location and color, but the border never shows up. I've tried to scale the rect down to see if it was clipping on the outside of the view somehow, but that didn't work either.

I looked around on StackOverflow, but there doesn't seem to be any questions that relate to this (the only candidate is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386399/cgcontextstrokerect-is-drawing-only-a-side-of-rect), but it deals with images, so I don't think that it can help me).

Some explanations of the following code :

- _card is a property that holds some information about the card which is used to determine how it will be drawn
- I know the code in the if statement is executing because the NSLog appears in the console

Here is my drawRect method in the view I'm talking about (the code in the _card.isSelected if statement is what I believe should produce the border) :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if ([_card isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] && [_card intValue] == -1) {
        NSLog(@"No card");
    } else if ([_card isKindOfClass:[Card class]]) {
        Card *card = _card;

        if (card.shouldAnimate) {
            [self fadeSelfIn];
        }

        if ([_card isKindOfClass:[WeaponCard class]]) {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        } else if ([_card isKindOfClass:[ArmorCard class]]) {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
        }

        if (card.isSelected)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor);
            CGContextStrokeRect(context, self.bounds);
            NSLog(@"Drawing border on selected card with bounds %@, NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
        }

        CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `CGContextFillRect` is drawing over your stroke lines. Fill first, then stroke:

```
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

if (card.isSelected) {
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor);

    // As rob mayoff points out in the comments, it's probably a good idea to inset
    // the stroke rect by half a point so the stroke is not getting cut off by
    // the view's border, which is why you see CGRectInset being used here.
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0.5, 0.5));
}
```

Comment: You will probably also want to inset your bounds rect: `CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0.5, 0.5));`.

Comment: If I do not inset the rect will the border be clipped outside the view?

Comment: Yes, the middle of the stroke line will be on the border of your view, making the line half inside your view and half outside (which does not get drawn because it's outside the bounds of the view). It's probably a good idea to inset it by half a point.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you want the stroked path to be entirely within the view's bounds (and thus not clipped), it should be inset by half the stroke's line width (as set by `CGContextSetLineWidth()`). The line width is often 1 point so insetting by half a point is appropriate. But if you're using a different line width, you need to inset differently.